# MappingException: The target-entity "entity" cannot be found in 'xxx\Entity\User#nhpProductIds'

Tags: symfony, doctrine, mapping, entity

I have a strange problem only on my production server where the mapping appears to be incorrect. It's working on my development server -- they are both up to date on git.

This is the error I'm getting on production:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
The target-entity Shawmut\ClientBundle\Entity\NHPProductId cannot be found in 'Shawmut\ClientBundle\Entity\User#nhpProductIds'.
```

From my Entity\NHPProductId:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="nhpProductIds")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="nhp_product_id_users", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
protected $user;
```

From my Entity\User:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NHPProductId", mappedBy="user")
 **/
protected $nhpProductIds;
```

Can anyone think of what is going wrong here?

EDIT: I was able to solve this by renaming my entity to **ProductId** instead of NHPProductId. I have no idea why this was causing the Entity to not be loaded, but that was the fix.

Comment: This sort of thing is typically a cache issue.  Delete the production server's cache and rebuild.

Comment: I have already cleared and re-warmed the cache. On warm, it gives me the [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException] error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being due to my entity's name. By renaming it to NhpProductId, the problem went away.

Comment: Refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745924/the-target-entity-cannot-be-found-in-mappingexception